# Error "No Viable Conversion From Returned Value of Type 'int[2]' to function return type 'vector<int>'"

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

coder newbie here, I have an issue on HackerRank. It tells me to make a function which compares the elements of 2 arrays and returns 2 values in an array. However I get the "No Viable Conversion" error. When I change the type of 'scores' to vector, I get a compiler error, saying "Segmentation Fault". What I would like to find out is what this is, why it happens and where I can find out more about this.

```
vector<int> compareTriplets(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
int sA = 0, sB = 0;
vector<int> scores;
for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
    if (a[i] > b[i]){
        sA++;
    }else{
        sB++;
    }
}
scores[0] = sA;
scores[1] = sB;
return scores;}
```

Comment: `vector<int> scores;` creates an *empty* vector, without any elements. Any index into the vector will be out of bounds.

Comment: Also, arrays and vectors are different, and you can't convert from one to the other.

Comment: Lastly, so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites are *not* any kind of teaching or learning resources. In fact attempting to use them as such could actually be harmful. Don't use such sites, instead get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) and take classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem is** that you created a vector of size 0(an empty vector) and then were trying to assign elements to its 0th and 1st index which didn't exist. You should use :

```
//pass the vector by reference instead of by value
vector<int> compareTriplets(const vector<int> &a,const vector<int> &b) {
int sA = 0, sB = 0;
vector<int> scores(2); //create vector of size 2
for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
    if (a[i] > b[i]){
        sA++;
    }else{
        sB++;
    }
}
scores[0] = sA;
scores[1] = sB;
return scores;
    
}
```

when creating the `std::vector` of a particular size.
**Secondly** you should pass the vectors `a` and `b` by reference instead of by value as i did in my example. This way it will be faster.

Comment: could you edit or rewrite the first block of code? i can t see it

Comment: never mind, i ll try it now

Comment: @HoriaDuna I have added the whole code block in my answer now that you need. Check it out.